# pyomo: minimal production time / BIG M

Tags: variables, cplex, pyomo

I am looking for a way to map a minimum necessary duty cycle in an optimization model.
After several attempts, however, I have now reached the end of my knowledge and hope for some inspiration here.

The idea is that a variable (binary) `mdl.ontime` is set so that the sum of successive ontime values is greater than or equal to the minimum duty cycle:

```
def ontime(mdl,t):   
    min_on_time = 3 # minimum on time in h
    if t < min_on_time: return mdl.ontime[t] == 0
    return sum(mdl.ontime[t-i] for i in range(min_on_time)) >= min_on_time
```

That works so far, if the variable `mdl.ontime` will not be recognized at all.

Then I tried three different constraints, unfortunately they all gave the same result: CPLEX only finds inf. results.
The first variant was:

```
def flag(mdl,t):
    return mdl.ontime[t] + (mdl.production[t]>=0.1) >= 2
```

So if `mdl.ontime` is 1 and `mdl.production` is greater or equal 0.1 (the assumption is just exact enough), it should be greater or equal 2: a logical addition therm.

The second attemp was quite similar to the first:

```
def flag(mdl,t):
    return (mdl.ontime[t]) >= (mdl.production[t] >= 0.1)
```

If `mdl.ontime` is 1, it should be greater or equal `mdl.production` compared with 0.1.

And the third with a big M variable:

```
def flag(mdl,t):
    bigM = 10**6
    return mdl.ontime[t] * bigM >= mdl.production[t]
```

`bigM` instead should be great enough in my case...

All of them do not work at all...and I have no idea, why CPLEX returns the error that there is only an infeasible solution.
Basically the model runs if I don't consider the ontime-integration.

Do you guys have any more ideas how I could implement this?
Many greetings,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

It isn't real clear what the desired relationship is between your variables/constraints.  That said, I don't think this is legal.  I'm surprised that it isn't popping an error....and if not popping an error, I'm pretty sure it isn't doing what you think:

```
def flag(mdl,t):
    return mdl.ontime[t] + (mdl.production[t]>=0.1) >= 2
```

You are essentially burying an inferred binary variable in there with the test on `mdl.production`, which isn't going to work, I believe.  You probably need to introduce another variable or such.

Comment: The goal of the constraints should be this: a variable (as time series) should have values greater than zero for a minimum length / duration. Otherwise it should be zero.